# Get multiple returns from one string function

Tags: c#, winforms

Based on /users/668272/bas dialog box. I tried writing more in order to get multiple values

```
public static class ControlInfo
        {
            public static TextBox[] TextData { get; set; }
        }

        public static class Prompt
        {
            public static Form prompt = new Form();
            public static void ShowDialog(string Text, string caption)
            {
                //string[] inputval = new string[6];
                prompt = new Form()
                {
                    Width = 500,
                    Height = 650,
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
                    Text = caption,
                    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
                };
                #region:create
                Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 20, Top = 20, Text = Text };
                TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 100, Width = 400 };
                Button confirmationok = new Button()
                { Text = "Save", Left = 250, Width = 100, Top = 550, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
                Button confirmationcancel = new Button()
                { Text = "Cancel", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 550, DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel };
                confirmationok.Click += (sender, e) => { Save(); };
                confirmationcancel.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };

                prompt.Controls.Add(confirmationcancel);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textBox1);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textBox2);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textBox3);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textBox4);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textBox5);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textBox6);
                prompt.Controls.Add(confirmationok);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel1);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel2);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel3);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel4);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel5);
                prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel6);
                prompt.AcceptButton = confirmationok;
                prompt.AcceptButton = confirmationcancel;
                prompt.ShowDialog();
            }

            public static void Save()
            {
                var cArray = prompt.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
                ControlInfo.TextData = cArray;
            }
        }
```

[Update] I tried using string[] to get the values but this keeps on happening: `return inputval;` 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' So how do I return the values to string[] array properly?

[Update 2] Fixed the problem by creating a TextData[] to store the values then calling it out like this `ControlInfo.TextData[0].Text`

Comment: Which part isn't working? Your title indicates you want "multiple returns". What do you mean by that? You can return a single `string` made up of a combination of your text box `Text` values, or a `List<string>` with one item for each textbox...

Comment: What do you want to return from this method?

Comment: multiple strings variable from multiple textboxes. The code works fine, I created the dialog and able to input the values but I don't know how to take them out. Example: I created another messagebox to show the values from the dialogbox but only the first textbox not the others.

Comment: Well because I want to create a second window that work as an input box. Here a img : imgur(.)com/a/G4d99Lv .

Comment: Basically Instead of making textboxes in the my current form.design would take up lots of space. So I want to make a pop-up window like messagebox and work as a input field

Comment: Instead of returning a string, return `List<string>`, `IEnumerable<string>`, `string[]` or any other suitable data structure.

Comment: I tried List<string> but failed and string[] get the errror: cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a Textdata class to store the values from dialog through SAVE button. The completed code is in the question

Comment: I don't get it why did someone put a downvotes on my question just because I updated it with solution :). So you want me to ignore it even I have solved the problem right mr Downvote :)